# HTMl5 required attribute not working when input type is image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I have a form with some html controls and i have a image button. on click of this button i am using ajaxcall inside the function.When clicking the image the server side code executed but the required attribute is not working.Could you please help..
Below is my html code

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="col span1of2" id="divUserInfo" runat="server">
        <ul class="form">
            <li class="form-item">
                <label>Achternaam*</label>
                <input type="text" required id="txtName" />
            </li>
            <li class="form-item">
                <label>Emailadres*</label>
                <input type="email" required id="txtEmail" />
            </li>
            <li class="form-item">
                <label>Klantnummer</label>
                <input type="text" id="txtCustomerId" />
            </li>
            <li class="form-item">
                <label>PostCode*</label>
                <input type="text" required id="txtPostCode" />
            </li>
            <li class="form-item">
                <label>Huisnummer*</label>
                <input type="text" required id="txtHouseNumber" />
                <div class="extend right">
                    <label>Toevoeging</label>
                    <input type="text" id="txtExtraHouseNumber" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="form-item">
                <label>Onderwerp*</label>
                <input type="text" required id="txtSubject" />
            </li>
            <li class="form-item">
                <label>Uw- bericht</label>
                <input type="text" id="txtComment" />
            </li>
        </ul>
        <input type="image" src="/images/buttons/btn_send.png" onclick="SaveContactFormDetails();" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `required` attribute works, but on form submission. The constraints are checked by the browser on form submission, but the code in the `onclick` attribute is executed first. That is, when the image is clicked on, its `onclick` code is run first, and only after that it will be treated as a submit button that causes constraint validation.

You can fix this by explicitly calling a checking function in the [Constraint Validation API](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-constraint-validation-api):

```
onclick=
"if(document.getElementById('form1').checkValidity()) SaveContactFormDetails();"
```